# Prevent Visual Studio to add break lines in switch-case statements

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to *prevent* Visual Studio (2010) "Format document" menu to format the `switch-case` statements as the following:

When I write my code like:

```
switch (value) {
    case "1": mode = Mode.One; break;
    case "2": mode = Mode.Two; break;
}
```

And then hit "Format document", Visual Studio adds break lines:

```
switch (value) {
    case "1":
        mode = Mode.One;
        break;
    case "2":
        mode = Mode.Two;
        break;
}
```

I have looked into the Formatting section of VS Options, but I can't find anything relevant.

[image: Options>Formatting]

(I do not have ReSharper installed)

Comment: Not that I know of, why? Is it important?

Comment: Do you use ReSharper? I have a hunch that ReSharper does that, not VS, so maybe check the ReSharper settings

Comment: @Nolonar: Why? Because I find my code easier to read in some circumstances. Important? Not really, but eh :p

Comment: I agree that it smells like R#er.

Comment: I'm looking at the Resharper menus and I don't see a way to do it there either. I think you're SOL.

Comment: Don't know why but it seems that VS2012 doesn't try to reformat case statement.

Comment: @Otiel Sorry, my mistake! I noticed that sort of stuff happening a lot more after I started using R#er

Comment: @Otiel I think it must be a plugin of some sort though, do you have coderush or something? I have tested this on VS Express and it doesn't do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the setting that caused this:

Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Wrapping > `Leave statements and member declarations on the same line` must be checked.

[image: Options dialog]

Comment: For VS2019 it's Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > Wrapping